# tsung load testing websockets limit

Tags: websocket, load, performance-testing, load-testing, tsung

i'm testing websockets with tsung and i can achive 4820 connections after that I get this error below, I have already increased the open files limits to 
kern.maxfilesperproc: 64000
kern.maxfiles: 524288

I would like to reach 50000 connections for example. I'm load testing from mac book pro with sierra os 10.12.6

```
    =ERROR REPORT==== 20-Oct-2017::16:30:41 ===
** Generic server <0.5350.0> terminating 
** Last message in was {'EXIT',<0.5437.0>,
                        {emfile,
                         [{erlang,open_port,
                           [{spawn,"/bin/sh -s unix:cmd"},
                            [binary,stderr_to_stdout,stream,in,hide,out]],
                           []},
                          {os,cmd,1,[{file,"os.erl"},{line,239}]},
                          {ts_os_mon_erlang,get_os_data,2,
                           [{file,"src/tsung_controller/ts_os_mon_erlang.erl"},
                            {line,297}]},
                          {ts_os_mon_erlang,node_data,0,
                           [{file,"src/tsung_controller/ts_os_mon_erlang.erl"},
                            {line,227}]},
                          {ts_os_mon_erlang,updatestats,3,
                           [{file,"src/tsung_controller/ts_os_mon_erlang.erl"},
                            {line,172}]}]}}
** When Server state == {state,{global,ts_mon},
                               10000,'tsung_controller@Simons-MacBook-Pro',
                               "Simons-MacBook-Pro",<0.5437.0>,false,[]}
** Reason for termination == 
** {function_clause,
       [{ts_os_mon_erlang,handle_info,
            [{'EXIT',<0.5437.0>,
                 {emfile,
                     [{erlang,open_port,
                          [{spawn,"/bin/sh -s unix:cmd"},
                           [binary,stderr_to_stdout,stream,in,hide,out]],
                          []},
                      {os,cmd,1,[{file,"os.erl"},{line,239}]},
                      {ts_os_mon_erlang,get_os_data,2,
                          [{file,"src/tsung_controller/ts_os_mon_erlang.erl"},
                           {line,297}]},
                      {ts_os_mon_erlang,node_data,0,
                          [{file,"src/tsung_controller/ts_os_mon_erlang.erl"},
                           {line,227}]},
                      {ts_os_mon_erlang,updatestats,3,
                          [{file,"src/tsung_controller/ts_os_mon_erlang.erl"},
                           {line,172}]}]}},
             {state,
                 {global,ts_mon},
                 10000,'tsung_controller@Simons-MacBook-Pro',
                 "Simons-MacBook-Pro",<0.5437.0>,false,[]}],
            [{file,"src/tsung_controller/ts_os_mon_erlang.erl"},{line,121}]},
        {gen_server,try_dispatch,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,616}]},
        {gen_server,handle_msg,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,686}]},
        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
```

ulmit -a

```
Simons-MacBook-Pro:bin simoncigoj$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 640000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

The error in jetty websocket app:

```
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.accept(ServerConnector.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Which server are you testing? Does the server itself impose limitations on the number of open connections? What does `ulimit -a` print out?

Comment: the server is an embeded jetty, I have not checked if it imposes restrictions but we have a production deploy of the app that accepts more then 60k of connections so I would say that the server is capable of more I will add the ulimit -a to the question

Comment: I have no idea why it doesn't work, especially with the open file limit set to 640K... did you try restarting?

Comment: @Myst yes I have tried restarting ... does not help

Comment: If you run the Ruby `iodine` server (install gem and use `iodine -www . -t 1`, no app required), you'll get a message similar to: `10240 max concurrent connections / open files` This will indicate if it's a process limit or a server issue with your implementation (internal limitation / unclosed sockets).

Comment: @Myst I got .... 6400000 max concurrent connections / open files

Comment: Since the hard limit is clearly 6400000 (iodine performs something similar to `ulimit -n <max>`), the "Too many open file" issue is probably related to the implementation rather than the environment. Are you sure the implementation isn't "leaking" connections (does it close obsolete connections / sockets)? Or maybe the implementation imposes internal limits?

Comment: @Myst.... in production the implementation is capable to accept more than 60k of connections so I assume it should not be an implementation issue... is there any other parameter that I have to set which could affect the open files limit